# Please tell me what font is this

Tags: font-identification

I have used it many times but today couldn't able to recall the font name.
Anybody who used this font or can help in identifying this font would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Seems like "Algerian" (see example below from a Word Document). It's a free font available [here](http://www.fontspace.com/alan-carr/algeria).

[image]

Comment: It really seems a lot like a compressed "Algerian".